# Make Shortcode Dependent Upon the Post ID where it is added

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I've been using a simple function to take the post title (also have one for tags and categories) and allow me to use a shortcode to display these on the front end of my site. The function I am currently using is below:

`function sc_title() {
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'title', 'sc_title' );`

Now I have recently started using a plugin called Templatera so I don't have to edit all of the pages individually, and this has stopped working correctly and is now pulling through the template title rather than the post title.

The response I have had from the plugin developer is:

> It will possibly require some changes made to the shortcode, so that
>   it is dependent upon the post id where it is being added.

I've tried several fixes but none seem to work.

Comment: you want to add short code only to specific post id?

Comment: I use the shortcode on all posts to show the post title within the content, not just one specific post.

Comment: I cannot able to get you, what exactly you want? you want a short code that will work for all post? or what ?

Answer (score 2):

In the Wordpress dev docs you can see that **get_the_title()** accepts an integer ID (or a post object) as a parameter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

Try to work that in your shortcode.

My first run would be:

```
function sc_title() {

    // get current post / page ID
    global $wp_query;
    $post_id = $wp_query->posts[0]->ID;

    return get_the_title( $post_id );
}
add_shortcode( 'title', 'sc_title' );
```

This works on single pages (e.g. a post "page"), but I guess it does not work on pages where multiple posts' content is being displayed (it always returns the first queried post's title).

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. This is the solution that solved my problem with get_the_title() while adding a shortcode within a Templatera component.

Comment: I was grabbing some dinamic shortcode i've made for bakery pluging, then added it to templatera, but shortcode was grabbing, templetera post id, with this, it got fixed.

Same as last comment this should be right answer.